# Which was first "Stronger" or "Harder, Better, Faster, Stronger"?

Tags: history, songwriter, daft-punk

As it is well known, [Stronger by Kanye West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stronger_(Kanye_West_song)) features [Harder, Better, Faster, Stronger by Daft Punk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harder,_Better,_Faster,_Stronger) (https://www.nme.com/blogs/nme-blogs/kanye-west-stronger-10-anniversary-2119541). A friend told me that is was actually the other way around: Kayne West developed the song first (but it wasn't popular), Daft Punk made it popular and Kayne West re-released it later (this time becoming famous). I was not able to find any evidence in the internet for this claim. Does any of you know what he was talking about? Is he right or is he wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no basis for the claim that "Kanye wrote it first".  In all the evidence quoted below, you'd expect Kanye to have made some claim publicly that he wrote the tune.

1) From the [NME article](https://www.nme.com/blogs/nme-blogs/kanye-west-stronger-10-anniversary-2119541#SH1lviAghdpallIJ.99) you quote :

> It could have all been so different though, as Kanye apparently hadn’t
>   even heard of Daft Punk just 12 months prior to the release of
>   ‘Stronger’. Producer A-Trak has explained how the sample came about:
>   “It sort of happened because Swizz Beats sampled ‘Technologic’ for
>   that Busta Rhymes record, ‘Touch It’. We were on tour in Europe in
>   2006, spending a lot of hours on the bus listening to the radio. Kanye
>   heard ‘Touch It’ and thought that beat was cool. I said, ‘He just
>   swooped up Daft Punk’. And Ye said, ‘Who?’. I just couldn’t believe
>   that Kanye had never heard Daft Punk.”

2)The songwriting credits for DP's "Harder, Better, Faster, Stronger" from the wikipedia article you quote are for "Thomas Banglater, Edwin Birdsong and Guy-Manuel de Homem-Christo", that is, the two members of Dp plus (the [much-sampled](https://www.whosampled.com/Edwin-Birdsong/)) [Edwin Birdsong](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2472691/#composer), whose song "Cola Bottle Baby" is sampled.

Kanye West's "Stronger" also samples "Cola Bottle Baby".  Again, in the wikipedia article, sections on [Recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stronger_(Kanye_West_song)#Recording) and [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stronger_(Kanye_West_song)#Composition), it's clear Kanye put a lot into "getting it right".

3) Again, from the same Wikpedia article, Kanye was [sued (unsuccessfully) for copyright](https://www.billboard.com/articles/columns/the-juice/464988/kanye-west-cites-nietzsche-while-fighting-claim-of-stealing) over "Stronger".